# Why doesn't tensorflow use `from_logits` automatically where needed?

Tags: python, tensorflow, logits

According to Andrew Ng, when using tensorflow for classification it's better to use `from_logits`. I.e. instead of:

```
model = Sequential([
   ...,
   Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')
])
model.compile(..., BinaryCrossentropy())
```

the advice is to use

```
model = Sequential([
   ...,
   Dense(units=1, activation='linear')
])
model.compile(..., BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits = True))
```

(and similar for multiclass).

As far as I understand, the only reason for doing so is to improve numeric stability.

This makes me wonder: why doesn't tensorflow do this transformation automatically? Surely the `compile` method must be able to see that a `sigmoid` activation function is used for the last layer, and then replace it with `linear` and effectively set `from_logits = True` internally? This would also allow TF to keep a consistent interface, e.g. make `.predict` working as expected.

Is there any reason why TF would not want to do this? E.g. are there use cases where the first example is preferred over the second? Is there a performance penalty?

Comment: The quesiton is more like regarding the API design choice of Keras. I think it's more fitted to the discussion forum.  https://discuss.tensorflow.org/